# How can you verify titanium backup is encrypting backups?

Tags: encryption, titanium-backup

In Titanium Backup Pro it has the option to encrypt backups. How can this be verified that it's working? It normally outputs a gz file with an apk inside. When I try to open the apk with a text editor it doesn't have any human readable text, so does that mean it's encrypted??

Answer (score 1):

As per [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/53557/46024) titanium does not encrypt apps binaries(apk). It just encrypts apps data.

Comment: Then how can I verify it is encrypting the data?

Comment: Try to open gz files for data with any unzip tool - it will give you an error. For more details including binary analysis see that link I have provided